# how to remove the index column in pandas?

Tags: pandas, indexing

In Pandas, when saving dataframe into csv file, there is always a index column showing row number, for example

[image]

how to get rid of this index?  I try to use the below code and it didn't work.

df1=df.reset_index(drop=True)

Thanks for your help.

Comment: `df.to_csv(file,index=False)`

Comment: Thanks Datanovice